# How to correctly use laravel-dompdf to generate pdf of view

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I have following view

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And used following code to generate pdf file

```
public function pdf()
{
    $view = view()->make('Article::print');
    $contents = $view->render();
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($contents)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false);
    return $pdf->download('santosh.pdf');
}
```

But it does not give correct output rather it return [image: Returned PDF view]

How can i solve it , please help

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: same as the design when we run the above snippet @BrianS

Comment: Heh, sorry I must've missed the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current release of Dompdf (0.7.0) has limited support for Bootstrap-based styling (see the [relevant issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631)). With the 0.7.1 Dompdf will come closer to being able to render your document, but I would still not recommend it until the following release (0.7.2?) because it is still missing some necessary capability with regard to the box-sizing CSS property.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pdf with complex design but you do can create pdf with simple design having simple css.

Comment: Hey, this is more a comment on the question rather than an answer since it gives a broad guideline but does not offer a specific solution to the specific problem faced by the OP. You might want to add a reference or give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

DomPDF supports limited number CSS items. If you need to complex html into PDF, please use wkhtml2pdf. It gives better output